# Fundamental theorem of Calculus: $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt$ Possible textbook mistake

Tags: calculus

using the FTC we are supposed to evaluate

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt
$$

and the answer, the textbook says, should be a constant. When I evaluate that derivative I get

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{0} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt + \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt\\
= - \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{-x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt + \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt\\
= - \frac{1}{3+(-x)^2} \cdot (-1) + \frac{1}{3+x^2}\\
= \frac{1}{3+x^2} + \frac{1}{3+x^2}\\
= \frac{2}{3+x^2}
$$

but I suppose that the textbook is expecting the answer $0$ (which for me is not correct since the chain rule, on the first term, makes the fraction not cancel). Is there really a mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks correct to me, and makes sense (for large $x$ you only add a little bit of area when you increase $x$ a little bit).

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did put the minus sign. Can you please review my answer?

Comment: I believe your answer is right. Intuitively, the answer cannot be zero because by increasing $x$, you extend the area of integration _both_ to the right _and_ to the left. Since the integrand is positive, the value of the integral must grow.

Comment: Another way to see that it is correct is to use that the integrand is even, $f(t) = f(-t)$ , so $F(x) = \int_{-x}^x f(t) dt = 2\int_0^x f(t)dt$ giving $\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = 2f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Note if the textbook was correct then the integral would be independent of $x$: clearly this is false because the function is always positive so increasing $x$ will add more to the integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{1}{3+t^2} \ dt
= 1\frac{1}{3+x^2}+1\frac{1}{3+(-x)^2}=\frac{2}{3+x^2}$$

Note that $$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} h(t) \ dt=f'(x)h(f(x))-g'(x)h(g(x))$$